# How to perform a query using a specific field of a node entity reference

Tags: 8, database

I have a content type that has a node entity reference field. My base query looks like

```
$event_nids = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
    ->condition('type', 'my_content_type')
    ->execute();
```

I'd like though to be able to sort by the title field of the referenced field type. I attempted

```
$event_nids = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
    ->condition('type', 'my_content_type')
    ->sort('field_referenced_node.title', ASC)
    ->execute();
```

But I receive the error

> Drupal\Core\Entity\Query\QueryException: Invalid specifier 'title' in Drupal\Core\Entity\Query\Sql\Tables->addField()

Is it possible to sort a node query by a field inside a referenced node?

Comment: Sure but you probably want to `sort` and not use a `condition` for this https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Query%21QueryInterface.php/function/QueryInterface%3A%3Asort/8.2.x

Comment: @tenken whoops, that was a typo, thanks, I went ahead and made the update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you want something like below. Note that this isn't really a database query at this level but an Entity Query:

```
$event_nids = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
  ->condition('type', 'my_content_type')
  ->sort('field_referenced_node.entity.title', ASC)
  ->execute();
```