# Node Reference Argument In loadByProperties() while Creating API

Tags: entities

I have a custom module which generates an API, I want the API to filter content based on a node reference field. How do I pass the field **field_author**(Entity Reference from another content type) field as an argument to loadByProperties?

```
public function get() {

$entities = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')- 
>loadByProperties(['field_author' => 'Holmes']);

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to perform a query using a specific field of a node entity reference](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/233241/how-to-perform-a-query-using-a-specific-field-of-a-node-entity-reference)

Comment: The id of the target entity, in your case $uid if you reference users, like in this answer $tid for taxonomy https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/234077/how-do-i-get-the-node-id-from-the-taxonomy-term-id

Comment: After the edit, if **field_author** targets another content type, then use $nid of the target.

Comment: @4k4 - its referenced from another content type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to 4k4

I modified my code to

```
    $entities = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')- 
    >loadByProperties(['field_author' => '469']);
```

Where 469 is the nid of my Referenced Node